# Searching the DOM for elements Vs. Searching an element for elements

Tags: javascript

Lets say I had a group of buttons in this structure, that I wanted to access through JavaScript

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="one">One</button>
  <button id="two">Two</button>
  <button id="three">Three</button>
  <button id="four">Four</button>
  <button id="five">Five</button>
  <button id="six">Six</button>
  <button id="seven">Seve</button>
  <button id="eight">Eight</button>
  <button id="nine">Nine</button>
  <button id="ten">Ten</button>
</div>
```

Efficiency-wise, would it be better to:

**A)** Use `document.getElementById` for it to scan the DOM each time, and get the buttons

**B)** Use `document.getElementById` to get a reference to `container`, then use `querySelector` on `container` to get each button, which saves having to search the DOM continuously?

Or is it indifferent?

Comment: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Comment: Fun fact (?) For this exact case it either doesn't matter at all because the engine has a shortcut `querySelector(`#`)` -> `getElementById` (e.g in Chromium based browsers), or `getElementById` will win because it's a simple key access (the document has to keep all named elements in a map), but the cases where this would matter are if you're on a page as huge as the full monopage Ecma Standards, on a slow device. But you'll certainly face other problems before having time to handle that one. Don't bother with that.